# Advice for PostgreSQL Options with Common Notes Functionality between three options

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-design

We are doing a new design for `notes`

We have three options for other database tables (`persons`, `stores`, `items`) to each have `notes` associated with them:

1. **No Association Table**

   - The `notes` table has separate columns for `person_id`, `store_id`, `item_id`.  Only one of the three can be non-null.
   - Benefits

     - More efficient joins (no association tables)
     - Can easily ensure single note only associated with one object (protection against future bugs)
     - Can ensure single note does not become 'orphaned' by having no references to it.
   - Drawbacks

     - Table design for `notes` not as elegant (subjectively) with many columns
     - If ever want to associate another object with `notes` have to add column to existing table
       [image: Option 1]
2. **Multiple Association Tables**

   - Have a table per association

     - One table for `person_id / note_id`
     - One table for `store_id / note_id`
     - One table for `item_id / note_id`
   - Benefits

     - Easy to add new association table when need `notes` for next object
     - `notes` table does not need extra columns for separate 'parents'
   - Drawbacks

     - Performance worse with extra join to find `notes` for any parent.
     - Larger number of association tables
       [image: Option 2]
3. **Single Note Group Association Table**

   - Every `note` has a `note_group_id`; many notes can all have the same `note_group_id`
   - Each `person` in the `persons` table has a single `note_group_id`.  Each `note` in the `notes` table with that same `note_group_id` all belong to that person.
   - Similarly for `stores` and `items`.
   - Benefits

     - Easy to add `notes` for a new parent - just add the `note_group_id` column.
     - `notes` table does not need extra columns for separate 'parents'
     - Single association table.
   - Drawbacks

     - Performance worse with extra join to find `notes` for any parent.
     - Harder when looking at the database to track which parent a `note` belongs to
     - Potentially easiest to have future coding mistakes and orphaned notes.
       [image: Option 3]

Overall do people have recommendations with one or more of these three options with a database with a few million notes.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't consider one `notes` table per "referenced" entity? A `person_notes`, `item_notes` etc. The columns common to all notes tables could be defined in a base table and the "specific" notes tables would then inherit from that table

Comment: I think you are overestimating the cost of joins when you say "Performance worse with extra join"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: To answer your first question: because most of the behaviour is common and therefore works well in a common table with common (Hibernate/Java) code above it.  There are lots of other columns in the notes table that I did not include because they are not relevant to the question.  
To answer your second question: We do a lot of joins in our queries and have historically found performance degradation with each join.  Or rather, that performance improved when we eliminated a join.